# how do I connect the key to the form?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p><button id="generate">Generate</button> <code id="outputs"></code></p>

<p><input [type=text]></input>
<button id="acc">Send</button></p>

(function() {
    function getRandomInt( min, max ) {
         return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) ) + min;
    }
    
    function generateProductKey() {
        var tokens = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
            chars = 5,
            segments = 4,
            keyString = "";
            
        for( var i = 0; i < segments; i++ ) {
            var segment = "";
            
            for( var j = 0; j < chars; j++ ) {
                var k = getRandomInt( 0, 35 );
                segment += tokens[ k ];
            }
            
            keyString += segment;
            
            if( i < ( segments - 1 ) ) {
                keyString += "-";
            }
        }
        
        return keyString;

    }
    
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var generate = document.querySelector( "#generate" ),
            output = document.querySelector( "#outputs" );
        
        generate.addEventListener( "click", function() {
        
            var productKey = generateProductKey();
            output.innerHTML = productKey;
            
        }, false);
        
    });
    
})();
```

This code generates random Key. What i want is how to make input check the generated Key and only accept it.
I mean how to make input accept only that generated key as valid.

i was thinking if i could make it with "if", but i didnt make it out.

Comment: What does "accept" mean? What would happen if the input wouldn't "accept" that generated key? What makes you think that "if" is relevant to the problem?

Comment: I want that input to get that generated Key, i mean when you click the button "send" it should check if whats in that input is Generated Key and send to page, i will add later

Comment: If you only want a generated key, then why do you have an input in the first place? Just submit the generated key.

Comment: FYI: Input is a replaced element. It has no closing tag and as such it is invalid to include one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a restructured program that is much easier to follow.

If you want to set the input value to the generated key, then do so.

```js
(function() {
  const TOKENS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

  let generateEl, inputEl, outputEl; // These will be set upon DOM ready

  // Wait for page to load, then call initialize
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize);

  function initialize() {
    generateEl = document.querySelector("#generate");
    inputEl = document.querySelector("#input");
    outputEl = document.querySelector("#output");

    generateEl.addEventListener("click", populateOutput, false);
  }
  
  function populateOutput() {
    const key = generateProductKey(5, 4);
    outputEl.innerHTML = key;
    inputEl.value = key;
  }

  function generateProductKey(chars, segments) {
    let keyString = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
      let segment = "";
      for (let j = 0; j < chars; j++) {
        segment += TOKENS[getRandomInt(0, TOKENS.length - 1)];
      }
      keyString += segment;
      if (i < (segments - 1)) {
        keyString += "-";
      }
    }
    return keyString;
  }

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
})();
```

```html
<p>
  <button id="generate">Generate</button>
  <code id="output"></code>
</p>
<p>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button id="acc">Send</button>
</p>
```